# Smarty - how to use comparison numbers

Tags: php, smarty

I'm doing this:

```
{if $categories->id !=86 && $categories->id !=87}

   xxxx code

{/if}
```

The `categories` is a `vector` and has id's from 1 to 140 or so, the id's 86 and 87 exist, I don't want to do the code on the pages with id's 86 and 87, but it is not working properly.

Comment: Is `$categories->id !86` misspelled? Should it be `$categories->id !=86`?

Comment: it was misspelled in here, on the code it was right, so the problem isnt that. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always execute because when you are in category 86 it evaluates to:

```
if (true && false) // returns false
```

You need to use XOR operator

```
{if $categories->id !=86 xor $categories->id !=87}

   xxxx code

{/if}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry missed the `dont wan't to execute part`

```
{if !($categories->id ==86 || $categories->id ==87)}
    xxx code
{/if}
```

Should be fine